# Conditionally prevent from value to change in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

When user tries to select another value in mat-select I want to show popup to confirm if user indeed wants to select another value. The problem in time I show popup visually the selected value is already presented in the mat-select. Can I somehow prevent this value to change until user decides to select? [Here is an example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2alu7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can't cancel the event as it is raised after the MatSelect value has already been changed.

However you can make use of the [pairwise](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) operator from rxjs to get the previous value included with the valueChanges event. Then it's just a matter of displaying the dialog to the user when the value changes, if they cancel the action then revert the value back to the previous (without emitting another event) and complete the event without processing the subscribe function by returning [EMPTY](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY).

This is much easier when using reactive forms as shown in [the updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrzffv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This example is broken. 1 - open page. 2 - select "Option 3". 3 - in popup select "No". 4 - Select "Option 2". 5 - in popup select "No". As result Option 3 is selected while user never agreed to change the value.

Comment: Save the select's value to a variable in the component and restore the FormControl value from that. You can update this variable's value in the confirmed subscription handler. Yes, an extra variable, which otherwise should've been handled in the FormControl, but this gets the job done. In this case, you can also view the FormControl as a 'temporary holder' of the user's preference until it's confirmed - if that helps to justify its existence.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need two things to - prevent value from being set and keep select's dropdown open. `event.stopPropagation()` will do that. In `<option>` use `div` to occupy most of the space:

```
<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let val of values" [value]="val">
```

Then set value to control value and close **MatSelect** if confirm dialog gets confirmed. Here I forked [full implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czftrt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by using MatSelectChange source.value prop.

```
currentValue = 0;
onSelectionChanged(event: MatSelectChange): void {

//rollback changing
event.source.value = this.currentValue;

//any other actions here e.g. dialog popup or anything else

// set updated value
this.currentValue = event.value;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change events are not cancellable.

To obtain this behaviour you should save the value to a property and then assign it to the dropdown while waiting for the result. The selected Value should be also saved and assigned after confirmation

```
previousValue = "Option 1";
new Value = "Option 1";

onValueChanged(e: Event) {
    this.newValue = e.value; // stores the furure value
    this.someSelectedValue = previousValue; // resets the value back before dialog
    this.openDialog();
  }
```

and then

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (res) {
        this.someSelectedValue = this.newValue;
      }
      //this.animal = result;
    });
```